# How to execute 2 different rest api json payload in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I am new to  powershell, I have been working on one task.

I have 2 JSON payloads which I got from different 2 different rest API in appcenter.

One JSON payload creates an app in appcenter and the other Json payload add the particular app to the  Teams in appcenter where users are grouped in single team.

So how can I use these 2 JSON in my powershell script and execute it (not sure i if I elaborated my question clearly).

Comment: are you looking for something [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6) like this?

Comment: You need `Invoke-RestMethod`. The JSON goes into the $body

Comment: when i try Invoke-Webrequest , now am getting this error Invoke-WebRequest : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. Even i tried these commands ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
 but no use.